# How to read JSON file , this is my version , but is not good

Tags: javascript

I can't read to JSON file, the error i received is :

```
     reject(err)
                ^

TypeError: reject is not a function
```

```
import fs from 'fs'
const FILE_NAME = '../assets/pies.json'
let pieRepo = {
    get: (resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(FILE_NAME, (err, data) => {
            if(err){
                reject(err)
            } 
            else{
                resolve(JSON.parse(data))
            }

        })
    }
}
export default pieRepo
```

Please forgive me if my question is to trivial

Comment: Where did you *expect* reject and resolve to come from? They're conventionally the names you'd use in a promise constructor callback, but you *don't actually have one*.

Comment: How is your function being called?

Comment: Will you try (resolve.data); in the else part.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: let me just add that you didn't add any context to the question and using resolve and reject as variables outside of promises doesn't make them inherit the promise syntax please read: [MDN Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

If you need a promise just add new Promise() just before what you have originally wrote

```js
import fs from 'fs'
const FILE_NAME = '../assets/pies.json'
let pieRepo = {
    get: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(FILE_NAME, (err, data) => {
            if(err){
                reject(err)
            } 
            else{
                resolve(JSON.parse(data))
            }

        })
    })
}
export default pieRepo
```

This above is not a function so you would use it as pieRepo.get if you want a function here is the code below

```js
import fs from 'fs'
const FILE_NAME = '../assets/pies.json'
let pieRepo = {
    get: () => {return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(FILE_NAME, (err, data) => {
            if(err){
                reject(err)
            } 
            else{
                resolve(JSON.parse(data))
            }

        })
    })}
}
export default pieRepo
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting local json data, I would do this way:

```
...
import jsonData from './pies.json'
...

function App(){

  ...
  //code to use jsonData
  console.log(jsonData);
  ...
  return (
  ...
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only missing the `Promise` constructor, like this

```
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readFile(FILE_NAME, (err, data) => {
        if(err){
          reject(err)
        } 
        else{
          resolve(JSON.parse(data))
        }
      })
    })
```

Then, you can use `then()` and `catch()` like `pieRepo.get.then(d => console.log(d))`.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend using Axios.

```js
Import fetch from 'axios'

const FILE_NAME = '../assets/pies.json'
fetch(FILE_NAME)
    .then(()out => {
    //as example, read the property "author"
    console.log(out.author)
})
```

Please note that this is pseudo-Code and I didn't test it.